# Остаточные параметры получить по ключу значения JS

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов. (urlParams.categories)

Хочу вывести с помощью оператора расширения (...) не все эти объекты целиком, а конкретное значение этих объектов по ключу (id). т.е. :
111,112,113 и тд.

Я могу это легко делать в цикле for in или forEach, но мне интересно можно ли это сделать при помощи (...)

Пытался делать это как-то так:

```js
let urlParams = {
  'categories': [
    { id: '111', name: 'test1' },
    { id: '112', name: 'test1' },
    { id: '113', name: 'test1' }
  ]
}

console.log(urlParams.categories)

console.log(...urlParams.categories.id)
```

Но не срабатывает.

Comment: не, при помощь `...` это сделать нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С предварительным `.map`:

```js
let urlParams = {
  'categories': [
    { id: '111', name: 'test1' },
    { id: '112', name: 'test1' },
    { id: '113', name: 'test1' }
  ]
}

console.log(...urlParams.categories.map(cat => cat.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит сначала найти индекс, а после, уже обращаться по индексу и выводить значение.

```js
let urlParams = {
  'categories': [{
      id: '111',
      name: 'test1'
    },
    {
      id: '112',
      name: 'test1'
    },
    {
      id: '113',
      name: 'test1'
    },
  ]
}
let index_id_111 = urlParams.categories.findIndex(item => item.id === '111');
console.log(urlParams.categories[index_id_111].name)
```